# PHPStorm. Быстрая документация по выделенному свойству

Tags: phpstorm, документация, расширения

Есть ли подобное расширение, как на Brackets( По хоткею вылазит окошко с документацией по выденному свойству)?
Знаю про `Сtrl+Q`, но встроенная документация настолько хилая, что всерьез ее воспринимать рука не поднимается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встроенная документация *наверняка* берётся с [PHP.Net](//php.net) и частично урезается. Это можно проверить, если сравнить, например, документацию по функции [`array_map()`](//php.net/array-map) (или любой другой).

Она не предназначена для изучения и играет роль шпаргалки. Однако, внизу окна есть ссылка на официальную документацию; но гораздо проще нажать `Shift+F1`:

[image: PHPStorm array_map() Documentation]

Исходя из вышесказанного, нет смысла делать какие-либо дополнительные плагины, так как у вас есть быстрый доступ к шпаргалке и официальной документации.

Официальная документация PHP «объезжана» годами и лучше её вы редко сможете что-то найти. Помимо основной информации на страницах, обращайте внимание на замечания, которые пишут пользователи — иногда они ценнее самой информации на странице. Плюс, вы также можете внести свой вклад в [PHP.Net](//php.net):

- https://edit.php.net;
- http://doc.php.net/tutorial.

---

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/documentation-tool-window.html

https://plugins.jetbrains.com